# Use sapply to obtain a vector of lists

Tags: r, functional-programming

Consider the following list:

```
temp <- list(1, "a", TRUE)
```

We can use `sapply` to replicate the list:

```
> ts <- sapply(1:5, function(x) temp)
> ts
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
id    1    1    1    1    1   
grade "a"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "a" 
alive TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

If I inspect the result using `typeof`, I obtain `list`. However, if I inspect it with `sapply`, I get this:

```
> sapply(ts, function(x) print(x))
[1] 1
[1] "a"
[1] TRUE
[1] 1
[1] "a"
[1] TRUE
[1] 1
[1] "a"
[1] TRUE
[1] 1
[1] "a"
[1] TRUE
[1] 1
[1] "a"
[1] TRUE
```

That is, when I inspect the same result with `sapply`, this vector of lists is treated as a matrix. Is there any workaround, or does R disallow a vector of lists in general? If the latter is the case, why do I get `"list"` from `typeof`?

PS: For my specific question, I understand the obvious solution of using lapply to switch to a list of lists. I am just curious and confused by R’s behavior.

Comment: have a look at `str(ts)` . It is a list (with dimension) not a matrix

Answer (score 0):

The return of `sapply(ts, function(x) print(x))` is still a list. Actually a list of 15 variables as 3 members of `temp` has been simplified and returned as 3 items (times 5 iterations). If you want something like `lapply` like output please try:

```
>ts <- sapply(1:5, function(x) temp, simplify = FALSE)
> ts
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "a"
#
#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] TRUE
#.......
#.......
```

Or even you can try:

```
>ts <- sapply(1:5, function(x) as.data.frame(temp))
```